# Create hyperlink in gmail to file on shared drive

Tags: gmail

I want to send to my team an email that includes a hyperlink to a file on a shared drive that we all have access to. I can open a pdf in chrome from windows explorer by either dragging and dropping it in chrome or by right clicking > Open with > chrome. Copying and pasting the resultant address reads file:///Z:/Instructions/MyInstructions.pdf (the Z drive being a shared drive). I want to create a hyperlink to this pdf in a gmail so that recipients will have the file open in chrome when they click on it. (I don't want them to have to copy and paste the address, though I realize that's rather simple). When I try creating a hyperlink in a gmail, the hyperlink doesn't carry over to the recipient, it merely remains plain text.

Is there a way to send a hyperlink of a path to a file in a shared drive though a gmail?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a desktop to send the email, then you can use the CTRL+K shortcut (or CMD-K shortcut if you are using Mac) to bring up the HyperText menu on Gmail.

From there you can enter the link and even choose custom text on the link as shown below.

[Example of HyperText Menu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVPa1.gif)

Comment: Thanks, I did try the Ctrl + K, and use the following as the web address: file:///Z:/Instructions/MyInstructions.pdf however this doesn't create an actual hyperlink.

Comment: @Iracambi Try using putting the address starting from the drive, for example : Z:/Instructions/MyInstructions.pdf